# STM32 - SBSFU start at different flash address

Tags: stm32

I have some trouble with the SBSFU (secure boot and secure firmware update) on a STM32F7. To start with, the STM32F722RE I'm using has 512kByte of flash and the following sectors:

[image]

Now the problem I have is, that I need two sectors (at the moment sector 2 and sector 3) for virtual eeprom emulation and the SBSFU needs 64kByte of flash. So either I start the SBSFU directly from sector 4 or I use sector 0,1 and 4. From my experiements so far, I am not able to achieve what I want, since always when I somehow split the SBSFU, the firmware bricks after I start the initial firmware flash process.

I really don't know I this is even possible what I'm trying if if so, how? When I have the SBSFU at the first 4 sectors, everything works and I can correctly update. So it is a linkerscript issue.

The linkerscripts looks like this (I tried to only have the vector table at 0x08000000 and the rest I shifted to 0x08010000):

**mapping_fwimg.ld**:

```
/* Active slot #1 : 1984 kbytes */
__ICFEDIT_SLOT_Active_1_start__  = 0x08020000;  
__ICFEDIT_SLOT_Active_1_end__    = 0x0805FFFF;
__ICFEDIT_SLOT_Active_1_header__ = __ICFEDIT_SLOT_Active_1_start__;

/* Slots not configured */
__ICFEDIT_SLOT_Active_2_header__ = 0x00000000;
__ICFEDIT_SLOT_Active_2_start__  = 0x00000000;
__ICFEDIT_SLOT_Active_2_end__    = 0x00000000;
__ICFEDIT_SLOT_Active_3_header__ = 0x00000000;
__ICFEDIT_SLOT_Active_3_start__  = 0x00000000;
__ICFEDIT_SLOT_Active_3_end__    = 0x00000000;
```

**mapping_sbsfu.ld**:

```
/* SE Code region protected by protected area */
VECTOR_SIZE = 0x400;
__ICFEDIT_SE_Code_region_ROM_start__       = 0x08010000; /*0x08010000 + VECTOR_SIZE;*/
__ICFEDIT_SE_CallGate_region_ROM_start__   = __ICFEDIT_SE_Code_region_ROM_start__;  /* No need to do +4 as we have dummy bytes in SE_CoreBin .ld file */
__ICFEDIT_SE_CallGate_region_ROM_end__     = __ICFEDIT_SE_Code_region_ROM_start__ + 0x1FF;

/* SE key region protected by protected area */
__ICFEDIT_SE_Key_region_ROM_start__        = __ICFEDIT_SE_CallGate_region_ROM_end__ + 0x1;
__ICFEDIT_SE_Key_region_ROM_end__          = __ICFEDIT_SE_Key_region_ROM_start__ + 0xFF;

/* SE Startup: call before enabling protected area*/
__ICFEDIT_SE_Startup_region_ROM_start__    = __ICFEDIT_SE_Key_region_ROM_end__ + 0x1;
__ICFEDIT_SE_Code_nokey_region_ROM_start__ = __ICFEDIT_SE_Startup_region_ROM_start__ + 0x100;
/* Aligned SE End at the end of the 1st 32Kbytes of flash, MPU protection isolation constraints */
__ICFEDIT_SE_Code_region_ROM_end__         =  0x08017FFF;

/* SE IF ROM: used to locate Secure Engine interface code out of protected area */
__ICFEDIT_SE_IF_region_ROM_start__         =  __ICFEDIT_SE_Code_region_ROM_end__ + 1;
__ICFEDIT_SE_IF_region_ROM_end__           = __ICFEDIT_SE_IF_region_ROM_start__ + 0x8FF;

/* SBSFU Code region */
__ICFEDIT_SB_region_ROM_start__            = __ICFEDIT_SE_IF_region_ROM_end__ + 0x1;
/* Aligned SE End at the end of the 1st 64Kbytes of flash, MPU protection isolation constraints */
__ICFEDIT_SB_region_ROM_end__              =  0x0801FFFF;

SE_Entry_Secure_ROM_Region_Length = __ICFEDIT_SE_CallGate_region_ROM_end__ - __ICFEDIT_SE_CallGate_region_ROM_start__ + 1;
SE_Key_region_ROM_Length          = __ICFEDIT_SE_Key_region_ROM_end__ - __ICFEDIT_SE_Key_region_ROM_start__ + 1;
SE_Startup_region_ROM_Length      = __ICFEDIT_SE_Code_nokey_region_ROM_start__ - __ICFEDIT_SE_Startup_region_ROM_start__ ;
SE_ROM_region_Length              = __ICFEDIT_SE_Code_region_ROM_end__ - __ICFEDIT_SE_Code_nokey_region_ROM_start__ + 1;
SE_IF_region_ROM_Length           = __ICFEDIT_SE_IF_region_ROM_end__ - __ICFEDIT_SE_IF_region_ROM_start__ + 1;
SB_ROM_region_Length              = __ICFEDIT_SB_region_ROM_end__ - __ICFEDIT_SB_region_ROM_start__ + 1;

/* RAM section */
/* SE RAM1 region protected by protected area */
/* SE stack is placed 1st in RAM, stack overflow does not write on other RAM area */
__ICFEDIT_SE_region_RAM_start__     = 0x20020000;
__ICFEDIT_SE_region_RAM_stack_top__ = 0x20020400;
__ICFEDIT_SE_region_RAM_end__       = 0x20020FFF;

/* SBSFU RAM1 region */
__ICFEDIT_SB_region_RAM_start__     = __ICFEDIT_SE_region_RAM_end__ + 0x1;
__ICFEDIT_SB_region_RAM_end__       = 0x2003BFFF;

SE_RAM_region_Length = __ICFEDIT_SE_region_RAM_end__ - __ICFEDIT_SE_region_RAM_stack_top__ + 1;
SB_RAM_region_Length = __ICFEDIT_SB_region_RAM_end__ - __ICFEDIT_SB_region_RAM_start__ + 1;

MEMORY
{
 SE_Entry_Secure_ROM_Region (rx)     : ORIGIN = __ICFEDIT_SE_CallGate_region_ROM_start__, LENGTH = SE_Entry_Secure_ROM_Region_Length
 SE_Key_region_ROM (rx)              : ORIGIN = __ICFEDIT_SE_Key_region_ROM_start__, LENGTH = SE_Key_region_ROM_Length
 SE_Startup_region_ROM (rx)          : ORIGIN = __ICFEDIT_SE_Startup_region_ROM_start__, LENGTH = SE_Startup_region_ROM_Length
 SE_ROM_region (rx)                  : ORIGIN = __ICFEDIT_SE_Code_nokey_region_ROM_start__, LENGTH = SE_ROM_region_Length
 SE_IF_region_ROM (rx)               : ORIGIN = __ICFEDIT_SE_IF_region_ROM_start__, LENGTH = SE_IF_region_ROM_Length
 SB_ROM_region (rx)                  : ORIGIN = __ICFEDIT_SB_region_ROM_start__, LENGTH = SB_ROM_region_Length
 SE_RAM_region (xrw)               : ORIGIN = __ICFEDIT_SE_region_RAM_stack_top__, LENGTH = SE_RAM_region_Length
 SB_RAM_region (xrw)               : ORIGIN = __ICFEDIT_SB_region_RAM_start__, LENGTH = SB_RAM_region_Length
}
```

**STM32F722x_FLASH.ld**:

```
/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = 0x2003C000;    /* end of RAM */
/* Generate a link error if heap and stack don't fit into RAM */
_Min_Heap_Size = 0;      /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x2000; /* required amount of stack */

INCLUDE mapping_fwimg.ld
INCLUDE mapping_sbsfu.ld

/* Specific SBSFU definition */
__ICFEDIT_intvec_start__    = 0x08000000;
SE_Binary_region_ROM_Length = __ICFEDIT_SE_Code_region_ROM_end__ - __ICFEDIT_SE_CallGate_region_ROM_start__ + 1;

/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{ 
 ISR_VECTOR (rx)               : ORIGIN = __ICFEDIT_intvec_start__, LENGTH = VECTOR_SIZE
 SE_Binary_region_ROM (rx)     : ORIGIN = __ICFEDIT_SE_CallGate_region_ROM_start__, LENGTH = SE_Binary_region_ROM_Length 
}

/* Define output sections */
SECTIONS
{
  /* The startup code goes first into FLASH */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >ISR_VECTOR
  .text.SE_CORE_Bin :
  {
    SE_CORE_Bin_start = .;
    KEEP(*(SE_CORE_Bin));
    SE_CORE_Bin_end = .;
  } > SE_Binary_region_ROM
  .SE_IF_Code : { KEEP(*se_interface_application.o (.text .text*))
                  KEEP(*se_interface_bootloader.o (.text .text*))
                  KEEP(*se_interface_common.o (.text .text*))
  } >SE_IF_region_ROM
  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
    *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
    *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
    *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
    *(.eh_frame)

    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(8);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
  } >SB_ROM_region

  /* Constant data goes into FLASH */
  .rodata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    *(.rodata)         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    *(.rodata*)        /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >SB_ROM_region

  .ARM.extab   : 
  { 
  . = ALIGN(8);
  *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
  . = ALIGN(8);
  } >SB_ROM_region
  .ARM : {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    __exidx_start = .;
    *(.ARM.exidx*)
    __exidx_end = .;
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >SB_ROM_region

  .preinit_array     :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >SB_ROM_region
  
  .init_array :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >SB_ROM_region
  .fini_array :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >SB_ROM_region

  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);

  /* Initialized data sections goes into RAM, load LMA copy after code */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */

    . = ALIGN(8);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
  } >SB_RAM_region AT>SB_ROM_region 

  
  /* Uninitialized data section */
  . = ALIGN(4);
  .bss :
  {
    /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss section */
    _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  } >SB_RAM_region

  /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough RAM left */
  ._user_heap_stack :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE ( end = . );
    PROVIDE ( _end = . );
    . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
    . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >SB_RAM_region

  

  /* Remove information from the standard libraries */
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    libc.a ( * )
    libm.a ( * )
    libgcc.a ( * )
  }

  .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
```

Here some sources:
https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/group0/33/ee/5b/6b/c7/43/44/3e/DM00414687/files/DM00414687.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00414687.pdf
https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/group0/94/71/5c/38/5b/ad/42/92/DM00414677/files/DM00414677.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00414677.pdf